# bash: apt-get: command not found

Tags: apt, virtualbox, sudo

I used "ubuntu-bionic-64" that I downloaded using `vagrant init`
after logging in using putty ssh successfully and tried to `sudo apt-get update` as a root user it said that `bash: apt-get: command not found`

Please lets me know what should I do next. Thank you!

Comment: So, I was able to use sudo apt-get directly at Virtual machine VirtualBox. I wasn't able to do it at the Putty ssh access!

Comment: Execute the command **vagrant up** and **vagrant shh**